# css style Replace inline one style name

Tags: javascript, css, regex, replace, styles

I have inline style css string and I want replace only one style name. I would like make universal regex for all style names.
REGEX:

```
/([a-z\-]+):\s*([a-z0-9]+);/mg
```

HTML:

```
<div style="top: auto; max-width:257px; left: 155px; right: auto; bottom: 88px; max-height: 313px; display: block;"></div>
```

Result (I want replace `max-width:257px;` to `max-width:20px;`):

```
<div style="top: auto; max-width:20px; left: 155px; right: auto; bottom: 88px; max-height: 313px; display: block;"></div>
```

The problem is that all style names is replaced to `max-width`:

```
<div style="max-width:20px; max-width:20px; max-width:20px; max-width:20px; max-width:20px; max-width:20px; max-width:20px;"></div>
```

https://regex101.com/r/5aHHZd/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a [cssText API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/cssText), with which one can set several CSS properties in one go. Its downside is that it replace all the existing styles.

So by create a tiny "custom" `setCSSText` function, you can do the same, though with the existing kept untouched.

Stack snippet

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');

setCSSText(div,"maxWidth:20px;color:red")

function setCSSText(el,ss) {
  ss.split(';').forEach(function(s){
    var pv = s.split(':');
    if (pv.length > 1) {
      el.style[pv[0].trim()] = pv[1].trim();
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div style="top: auto; max-width:257px; left: 155px; right: auto; bottom: 88px; max-height: 313px; display: block;">Some dummy text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you contradict yourself in your question. You say that the regex is for all style names but you only want to change a specific CSS property. Secondly, I can't possibly fathom why you need a regular expression to target this property. You can select this property using CSS and JavaScript and change it to whatever value you want.

CSS:

```
div{ max-width: 20px; }
```

JS:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.maxWidth = "20px";
```

EDIT:
IN response to your comment, I would take a look at the jQuery css() method.
https://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/jquery_css.asp
This basically allows you to set any css property.

Comment: But I need universal function, because in parameter I take `color:red;` or `min-height:30px` or `padding: 100px; border: 1px solid black;`. And I would have to write a function that takes every style name